# Collapsing in bootstrap is not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Web page is functioning properly but when I change the size of it(make smaller) and click on the button it does not collapsing.Below is my code.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Template 1</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

        </head>

        <body>

            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">zdfgdfgf</a>
                    <a class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    </a>

                    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li class="active"><a href = "#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Social media</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>


                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

can anyone help with this??

[image: this happened after fixing the collapsing problem using the 1st answer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that bootstrap.js must be loaded after jquery, like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: that fixed the collapsing problem.but now it is collapsing as in the picture above..I need to collapse it from the next line.that means the Home link should come to the next line.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle (assuming bootstrap 3) [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/0e9peu3r/)